# In my code i want to add my password number + strings , for example 1234xyz

Tags: python, string, integer, passwords

here is my code

```
   name = input("Enter your name:")
    print("Hello, " +name)
    age = input("Please enter your age:")
    # do exception handling to make sure age is in integer format
    age = int(age)
    if age >18:
      print("welcome")
```

#here i want to add my password number + strings

```
password = input("type your code now")
password = int(password)
if password==1234xyz: 
   print("okay")
else :
   print("wrong")
    
if age < 18:
    print("chole jao")
```

i want to add passwor liek 12323rtrt

Comment: yes i dont know how to use it , i am new .

Comment: now i edited , please help me now

Answer (score 0):

1. You could do the error handling like follows -

   ```
   name = input("Enter your name:")
   print("Hello, " +name)
   age = input("Please enter your age:")
   # do exception handling to make sure age is in integer format
   if age.isdigit() == True:
       age = int(age)
       if age >18:
           print("welcome") 
   else :
       print('age should be a positive integer')
   ```
2. In the second case, you need to know that you cannot convert a string which as alphabets into an integer. So `int(password)` won't work if the password has some characters. Also, you don't really need to convert the password to an integer. You can directly check/compare the user-inputted password against correct password as follows -

   ```
   password = input("type your code now")

   if password=='1234xyz': # note '1234xyz'  which is string can directly be used and this is correct way
      print("okay")
   else :
      print("wrong")
   ```